# Simple Controller Test failing in Rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, railstutorial.org

I'm working my way through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I hit a snag in Chapter 3 Section 3 on Testing. After generating two controllers - home and help, I ran the following in the terminal:

```
bundle exec rake test
```

The test should have passed but I received the following error for both the home and help controllers:

```
1) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/controllers  /application_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
    render :text "hello, world!"
                  ^
    app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have reviewed the code and haven't seen anywhere the end keyword should be required.

My static_pages_controller_test.rb file is setup as follows:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb has the following code:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

application_controller.rb has this code:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello
    render :text "hello, world!"
  end
end
```

routes.rb has this code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/help'
  root 'application#hello'
end
```

Any thoughts on what the problem might be? I have search this site with no luck. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but isn't it should be like this

`respond_to do |format| 
    format.html
    format.js { render :text => "hello, world!" } 
end`

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I'm trying to keep the code used in the tutorial as is so I don't run into problems when I get further along. I'm thinking that something may be awry outside of StaticControllerPages to cause a problem with the code I have. Thanks again for your help.